# Como adicionar imagem na segunda página com setAbsolutePosition iTextSharp C#?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o `setAbsolutePosition` para adicionar uma imagem na segunda página do documento construido no `iTextSharp` PDF. se possível, como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `setAbsolutePosition` você seta a posição da imagem.

Para adicionar a imagem na segunda página do documento utilize: `NewPage()`.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 20, 20, 20, 20);
// O que você quer na primeira página
document.NewPage();
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.

Comment: @TotallyUncool, não deixe de aceitar a reposta como aceita isso incentiva  o pessoal a continuar respondendo. Caso tenha duvida de como fazer consulte [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso e pelas edições, minha primeira pergunta e eu não tinha pego muito bem os esquemas de fazer pergunta.